# How can I prevent my divs from overlapping when the browser is resized?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am not good with CSS and am having some serious issues. I have a web page at: http://mrwongsdeals.com/eventsearch.html that gets messed up when the browser is resized. The div containing the banners at bottom over laps the form elements. I need it to be pushed down. I have tried adding `position = relative` to the div below but then I end up seeing scroll bars at the right.

Can someone in plain English assist me with what to do?

Comment: Could you post this example in jsfiddle.net? it will increase the chance to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position = absolute` means offset (top, left, bottom, right) from the first parent element with `position = relative` in the hierarchy, or if no parent with `position = relative` exists the document itself. The images in the .gallery div are positioned absolute, but there is no parent element that is positioned relative and therefore the left, top offset values that you set on the img elements count from the edges of the document and not the edges of the .gallery div.

To correct this, set the position attribute of the .gallery div to relative and adjust the offset (top, left, etc.) of the images inside that div to position them exactly where you want them.

Comment: A very good explanation on why does position: relative should solve the problem.

Comment: Very good explanation however now I have done position = relative and as mentioned before, there are scroll bars on right?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to the gallery class.

Comment: BTW, this page is not made for small displays. The banners are never going to show up probably with the current CSS.

Comment: I am using jQuery Mobile which is meant for mobile devices.

Comment: I'm talking about the CSS. This page could be done in a better way. :-)